# Laptop with Windows 7 using Virgin Mobile Broadband with ethernet cable cannot connect to Xbox Live 

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, connection-sharing, mobile-broadband

I've been trying for 3days! I get all the way to the part when it says it's connecting and it stops... maybe a problem with the IP address... not sure.

I have a toshiba satellite C655-S5132

Comment: Not a Virgin Broadband customer (I'm presuming in the UK) have you go to open any specific ports in your router?